# Symmetric states of a Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose states $i, j$ are symmetric in a Markov Chain, i.e.:

$P(T_j<T_i\mid X_0=i)=P(T_i<T_j\mid X_0=j):=\theta$,$\quad$  where $T_i=\min\{n\geq1:X_n=i\}$.

Denote $N$ as the number of visits to state $j$ before visiting state $i$. I cannot see why $P(N\geq k\mid X_0=i)=\theta(1-\theta)^{k-1}$  holds.

I think it should be $P(N=k\mid X_0=i)=\theta(1-\theta)^{k-1}$, because for $k-1$ times, the chain doesn't arrive state $j$, and at the $k$th time, the chain arrives at $j$.

Comment: If $X_0=i$, $N=k$ corresponds to the paths such that $i\to j$ then $j\to j$ $k-1$ times then $j\to i$, hence $P_i(N=k)=\theta(1-\theta)^{k-1}\theta$, which indeed yields $P_i(N\geqslant k)=\theta(1-\theta)^{k-1}$.

Comment: oh.. sure! thank you!

Comment: @Did here you seem to be assuming that there are only 2 states, $i$, and $j$.  How can you make that assumption?  There doesn't appear to be an assumption like that in the OP's question.

Comment: @guimption No assumption that there are 2 states. Any number of states, finite or countable.